# NXP lpc43s50 processor programming

Tags: arm, nxp-microcontroller

I want to use  NXP LPC 43s50 arm processor to control interface circuit but I don't know how to send my code into the processor. Please do suggest kits and programs for processor programming .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **KEIL ULINK JTags** along with **KEIl MDK** for programming processor . Keil supports  **NXP LPC43S50**. [Exmaples and support](http://www.keil.com/dd2/nxp/lpc43s50/)

Other various options are

> [pemicro](http://www.pemicro.com/arm/device_support/NXP_LPC/LPC43xx/LPC43S50/LPC43S50FET256/index.cfm)
>
> [IAR workbench](https://www.iar.com/iar-embedded-workbench/partners/nxp/downloads-for-nxp-kits/)

Comment: thanks a lot my friend but ı want to programme the processor and connect processor a ethernet cable. can  these applications make this

Comment: ın addition ı want to connect ethernet port to my processor .how can ı do that ?

Comment: Example Link has demo programs for to setup sever for the same.                      
 [Hitex LPC4350 Evaluation board](http://www.nxp.com/products/developer-resources/software-development-tools/software-tools/lpcxpresso-boards/hitex-lpc4350-evaluation-board:OM13031)  has Ethernet support .

Comment: Glad I could help @hilmiceylan. So  shall I edit the answer in order for this question to be closed, as answered!!!

Comment: ı dont know whether lpc43s50 has  already got bridge connections and ethernet connections , ı also dont know  for example whether ethernet is already connected or not

Comment: ı couldnt understand from the datasheet and there is not enough information about this processor so ı couldnt understand  whether this is only a processor  or  is there some other part which has already connected to processor for example ethernet and bridge connections?

Comment: can you please send me picture of device that you have @hilmiceylan

Comment: sorry but ı havent bought this device yet

Comment: The nxp datasheet provides enough information about the processor. It explains only about the processor not any other parts . If you need to develop on the processor try evaluation board mentioned before .